# Adding Data to multidemensional array after or before foreach()

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

ich have thios foreach loop to create an array. After or before it is created by the foreach, I want to add some values manually.
I tried it in this way:

```
                $data = array();
            foreach ($xyz as $single):
                    $data[$dynamic_name] = $single->xyz;
            endforeach;
            $data[oid] = '####';
```

but in this way, only the last added values (oid) are stored in the rray. The rest gets deleted. Where ist the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you are overwriting $dynamic_name on each pass of the loop.  Also you have two arrays in the example code.  I think you may want something like:

```
$data = array();
foreach($xyz as $single)
{
    $data[] = $single->xyz;
}
$data['oid'] = '####'
print_r($data);
```

If this is not what you meant, please post more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're code isn't correct PHP and I have trouble reading your question. I have the idea that you want to add entries to an array at multiple moments in your code.

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data[] = "First item before foreach";

$xyz = array();
$xyz[] = "1";
$xyz[] = "2";
$xyz[] = "3";

foreach ($xyz as $single) {
    $data[] = $single;
}

$data[] = "Last item after foreach";

var_dump($data);
?>

array(5) {
[0]=>
string(25) "First item before foreach"
[1]=>
string(1) "1"
[2]=>
string(1) "2"
[3]=>
string(1) "3"
[4]=>
string(23) "Last item after foreach"
}
```

Have a look at the PHP site for more information about this topic.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php